Question in Matrix Calculus.
Let $\Phi$ be a $n \times d$ matrix ($n > d$ and assume full rank). Let $b$ be a constant vector of size $n$. Consider the following problem
$$\frac{d}{d \Phi} b^\top \Phi (\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b.$$
This is what I have tried. Let $v = \Phi^\top b$ and $A = \Phi^\top \Phi$. Then the expression becomes
$$\frac{d}{d \Phi} v^\top A^{-1}v$$
We can use product rule like follows
$$\frac{d}{d \Phi} v^\top A^{-1}v = \frac{d}{d \Phi} Trace(v^\top A^{-1}v) = Trace\Big(\frac{d}{d \Phi} A^{-1}v v^\top\Big) = Trace \Big(\frac{d A^{-1}}{d \Phi} v v^\top +  A^{-1}\frac{d v v^\top}{d\Phi}\Big)$$
$$ = \frac{d}{d \Phi} v^\top A^{-1}(\Phi)v + \frac{d}{d \Phi}Tr\Big(A^{-1}v(\Phi)v(\Phi)^\top\Big) = \frac{d A }{d \Phi}\frac{d v^\top A^{-1} v}{d A} + \frac{d vv^\top}{d \Phi} \frac{d \;Tr\Big(A^{-1} vv^\top\Big)}{d vv^\top} $$
$$= -2\Phi A^{-1}vv^\top A^{-1} + 2bb^\top\Phi A^{-1}$$.
Here I used the following inequality in the last line $\frac{v^\top A^{-1} v}{d A} = -A^{-1}vv^\top A^{-1}$. Any comments, suggestions, or corrections regarding the derived expression's correctness are appreciated.

@hff1 Is the derived expression correct?

Your use of the "chain rule" with $\frac {dA}{d\Phi}$ doesn't really make sense here. I'm also not sure about your expression for $\frac{dvv^T}{d\Phi}$.

@BenGrossmann $\frac{d vv^\top}{d \Phi} = \frac{\Phi^\top bb^\top \Phi}{d \Phi} = bb^\top \Phi + (\Phi^\top b b ^\top)^\top$. At least in terms of dimensionality..

@rostader Ah, that makes sense now. Yeah that's correct

It is apparent that you are after the numerator-layout derivative.
Your computation is incorrect. Here is a computation along the lines of the "differential form" calculation demonstrated here.
We will make use of the following "derivative rules" regarding the differential:
$$
d[f(X)g(X)] = df(X)g(X) + f(X)dg(X)\\
d[f(g(X))][dX] = df(g(X))[dg(X)[dX]]\\
d(MX) = MdX\\
d(X^{-1}) = -X^{-1}dXX^{-1}
$$
With that, we have
\begin{align*}
d[b^\top \Phi &(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b] 
\\&= 
d[b^\top \Phi](\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b + b^\top \Phi d[(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}]\Phi^\top b + b^\top \Phi (\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}d[\Phi^\top b]
\end{align*}
The first and third terms are transposes of each other, which means that (since they're numbers) they are equal. Thus, we can express the above more simply as
$$
df = b^\top \Phi d[(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}]\Phi^\top b  + 2d[b^\top \Phi](\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b
$$
Writing $d[b^T \Phi] = b^\top d\Phi$, we simplify the second term to get
$$
2b^\top d\Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b = 2\operatorname{tr}[
(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b b^\top d\Phi
].
$$
Continuing with the first term, we have
\begin{align*}
d[(\Phi^\top \Phi^{-1})] &= 
-(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}d[\Phi^\top \Phi](\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}
\\ & = 
-(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}((d\Phi)^\top \Phi + \Phi^\top d\Phi)(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} 
\\ & = 
-(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}(d\Phi)^\top \Phi (\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} 
-(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top d\Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}, 
\end{align*}
so that
$$
b^\top \Phi d[(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}]\Phi^\top b  = \\
-b^\top \Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}(d\Phi)^\top \Phi (\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top b 
-b^\top \Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top d\Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top b.
$$
Again, we see that one term is the transpose of the other, so that the whole thing reduces to
$$
-2b^\top \Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top d\Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top b = \\
-2\text{tr}[(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top bb^\top \Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top d\Phi]
$$
Putting everything together, we have
$$
df = \text{tr}\left[\left(-2(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top bb^\top \Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top + 2(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b b^\top\right)d\Phi \right]
$$
Converting this to a numerator-layout derivative, we have
$$
\frac{df}{d\Phi} = -2(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top bb^\top \Phi(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top + 2(\Phi^\top \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^\top b b^\top\\
= - 2A^{-1}vv^\top A^{-1}\Phi^\top + 2A^{-1}\Phi^\top bb^\top.
$$

Never heard of people referring to matrix derivatives as having "numerator/denominator layouts." Isn't this just computing a Jacobian vs. a gradient?

@whp I haven't heard the term "Jacobian" used to refer to the matrix representation of the derivative of a function $f:\Bbb R^{m \times n} \to \Bbb R$; in my experience the Jacobian matrix is necessarily the derivative of a function from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$. In any case, the point is that there are two common ways of representing the derivative as a matrix in this context, and one is the transpose of the other.

@whp In this context, $M = \frac{df}{d\Phi}$ is a $d \times n$ matrix such that
$$
f(\Phi + \Delta \Phi) = f(\Phi) + \operatorname{tr}[M\Delta \Phi] + o(\Delta \Phi).
$$

Thank you, that makes sense. The way I was taught was that the Jacobian is the linear operator whose action yields the directional derivative and the gradient is the representation of that linear operator induced by an inner product and the Reisz theorem in the case where the function's output is one-dimensional. I suppose the nomenclature does get a bit garbled when dealing with spaces of matrices.

@whpowell96 Ok, so we are on the same page. The catch here is that there is no standard matrix representation of a map $J:\Bbb R^{n \times d} \to \Bbb R$, so no matrix is, properly speaking, the "Jacobian". Interestingly, the gradient is still the gradient in this sense; we're just using the Reisz theorem with the inner product $\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$. With the nomenclature I referred to, the gradient is the "denominator layout" derivative.

Yes, this makes sense. In practice, one is typically just interested in computing the action $J d\Phi$ so explicit matrix representations aren't really necessary. You'd be surprised how often people mistakenly work with the Frobenius or standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ without even realizing that it isn't appropriate. It comes up a lot in numerical PDEs where quadrature or meshing induces a weighted inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be consistent with some $L^2$ inner product, but there are many published papers where people use the standard one anyway

@whp Good to know, thanks for sharing

$
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\r#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\r{\LR{#1}}}
\def\GLR#1{\g{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\b{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\M{A^{-1}}
$I'll use $P$ instead of ${\large\Phi}$ for typing convenience and also define the symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
&A = P^TP,\qq B = bb^T \\
}$$
Let's also denote the insanely useful double-dot product with a colon
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}Y_{ij} \;=\; \trace{X^TY} \\
Y^*:Y &= \frob{Y}^2 \qquad \{ {\sf Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
X:Y &= Y:X \;=\; Y^T:X^T \\
\LR{PQ}:Y &= P:\LR{YQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TY} \\
}$$

Use the above notation to write the function of interest
and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= B:\LR{P\M P^T} \\
df
 &= B:\LR{\r{dP}\,\M P^T + P\M\,\r{dP^T} + P\:\r{d\M}\,P^T} \\
 &= \LR{BP\M}:dP + \LR{\M P^TB}:dP^T + \LR{P^TBP}:d\M \\
 &= \LR{BP\M}:dP + \LR{BP\M}:dP + \LR{P^TBP}:\r{d\M} \\
 &= \LR{2BP\M}:dP + \LR{P^TBP}:\RLR{-\M\,dA\,\M} \\
 &= \LR{2BP\M}:dP - \LR{\M P^TBP\M}:\g{dA} \\
 &= \LR{2BP\M}:dP - \LR{\M P^TBP\M}:\g{2\sym{P^TdP}} \\
 &= \LR{2BP\M}:dP - 2\sym{\M P^TBP\M}:\LR{P^TdP} \\
 &= \LR{2BP\M}:dP - 2P\lR{\M P^TBP\M}:dP \\
 &= 2\LR{BP\M - P\M P^TBP\M}:dP \\
\grad{f}{P}
 &= 2\LR{BP\M - P\M P^TBP\M} \\
}$$
This confirms the result that you derived in your post,
but doesn't validate the methods which you employed,
e.g. taking the trace of a matrix-by-matrix gradient.
